# I've two virtual host in my wamp server but one is work in google chrome another not work

Tags: localhost, wamp, virtual, host

This site can’t be reached
ecommercexpart.local’s server IP address could not be found.
Search Google for ecommercexpart local
ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Comment: I agree with @B001. However judging by what I can make of your question, I'd check that `ecommercexpart.local` actually resolves to an IP.

Comment: sorry for that. i have two virtual host. one is themexpart.com and ecommercexpart.com. but themexpart.com work properly but ecommercexpart.com not working.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your `ecommercexpart.local` hostname resolves to an IP address. You can do this by opening cmd and typing:

```
ping ecommercexpart.local
```

Chrome's ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED error points to this problem. Your hostname isn't resolving correctly, so it won't load.